# Slider breaking when going to another page and coming back to page with slider

Tags: jquery, reactjs, bxslider

I created a react project using create-react-app.

In the public index.html page, I load jQuery and BxSlider.

In App.js I assign the routes to page components.

On the homepage, route '/', I have a slider. When I go to another route, like '/contact' and come back, the slider breaks. The slider works, but when I comeback to the home route, all the slides show up.

Any ideas? Am I supposed to reload BxSlider.js and jQuery.js?

Thanks